# finding how many of a nested dictionary key inside a list

Tags: python, json

I need to find how many occurrences of key 'p' in a dictionary. The key is nested in a dictionary inside a list like this:

```
    {
"confidence": 0.2802316236036372,
"words": [
    {
        "p": 0,
        "c": 1,
        "s": 1420,
        "e": 4250,
        "m": "turn",
        "w": "Jennifer"
    },
    {
        "p": 1,
        "c": 0.487,
        "s": 1420,
        "e": 1620,
        "w": "Hi"
    }]}
```

I tried this:

```
    import json
    import pprint

    data = json.load(open ('test.json'))

    data_list = data["words"]

    for word in data_list:
        x = str(word['p'])

       # word_list = []
       # word_list.append(x)
```

but it just returns each in individual strings. I tried appending those to a list without success. I was also thinking of making a for loop and just counting how many there are but that seems like a clunky method. How could I:
1. create a list of all the strings together, so I could remove the last one? OR
2. create one string of all the strings, so I could similarly remove the last one? OR
3. loop through each "word" in data_list and count them? OR
4. get a list of all the strings, and then get the length of that list?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over-thinking it. To check if a key is in a `dict`, you just do `some_key in some_dict`. So, you can simply use `sum` on that:

```
In [6]: d = {
   ...: "confidence": 0.2802316236036372,
   ...: "words": [
   ...:     {
   ...:         "p": 0,
   ...:         "c": 1,
   ...:         "s": 1420,
   ...:         "e": 4250,
   ...:         "m": "turn",
   ...:         "w": "Jennifer"
   ...:     },
   ...:     {
   ...:         "p": 1,
   ...:         "c": 0.487,
   ...:         "s": 1420,
   ...:         "e": 1620,
   ...:         "w": "Hi"
   ...:     }]}

In [7]: data_list = d['words']

In [8]: sum('p' in sub for sub in data_list)
Out[8]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `sum` functions in a list comprehension:

```
data_list = {'confidence': 0.2802316236036372, 'words': [{'c': 1, 'e': 4250, 'm': 'turn', 'p': 0, 's': 1420, 'w': 'Jennifer'}, {'p': 1, 'c': 0.487, 'e': 1620, 's': 1420, 'w': 'Hi'}]}
the_count = sum(sum('p' in c for c in b) for a, b in data_list.items() if isinstance(b, list))
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: He's only interested in `data_list['words']`, why loop over all of `data_list`?